# SVM reports different AUC if binary labels 0 and 1) are swapped

Tags: svm, roc, auc

I am using a SVM classifier on an highly imbalanced binary data-set (about 10:1 ratio of the majority class to the minority class). I assign the majority class a label of 1 and the minority class to 0. This gives me the first figure (left) - the classifier reports an AUC of 0.82.

If I switch the class labels to be 0 for the majority class and 1 for the minority class, I get a substantially different result (figure right, AUC 0.77). What is causing this discrepancy?

(The results hold if the labels are 1 and -1 as well)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this should happen; I'd be interested in seeing your code.

There are two places to look for the change: the model's fit and predictions, and the production of the ROC curve.

For an SVM, I would expect the separating plane to be the same after swapping labels.  And then the distance from the plane (which is probably used as the basis for confidence measures in the ROC definition) would just swap sign.  A quick test with a nonlinear kernel suggests the same result, but I'm not as sure about it.

Assuming the model's rank-ordering hasn't changed, the ROC [should just be mirrored](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593502/232706) along the diagonal $y=1-x$, and so the AUC shouldn't change.